# Extract DOM element values grouped by their parents with XPATH using R

Tags: r, dom

I need a list, whose each element contains a character vector of author names from XML data pasted below, i.e. something like this:

```
[[1]]
"Giada De Laurentiis"
[[2]]
"J K. Rowling"
[[3]]
"James McGovern", "Giada De Laurentiis", ...
```

etc.

I started by this:

```
my_titles_nodeset <- xpathSApply(doc = my_dom, path = "//book")
```

I thought I got a separate DOM for each book, and I wanted to do this with each book (I am showing the operation just on the third book, skipping the `apply` functions):

```
  > (title <- my_titles_nodeset[[3]])
    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <author>Per Bothner</author>
      <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
      <author>James Linn</author>
      <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
```

I seemed to get what I wanted - the third book only. So I wanted to extract the authors:

```
> (author_group <- xpathSApply(title, path = "//book/author", xmlValue))
```

But I got all authors of all books on one heap again! See below:

```
 > (author_group <- xpathSApply(title, path = "//book/author", xmlValue))
[1] "Giada De Laurentiis"    "J K. Rowling"           "James McGovern"        
[4] "Per Bothner"            "Kurt Cagle"             "James Linn"            
[7] "Vaidyanathan Nagarajan" "Erik T. Ray"
```

1. How shall I proceed to get the desired list (see top), as simply as possible?
2. What has happened, and is the issue related to the XML package, or R in general, or XPATH?

*This is the first time I am using XPATH and I can only code in R, please do not use other programming languages for explanation.*

### The XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the author information in two steps. First step go to the level of books and then to the authors.

```
listBooks <- xpathApply(my_dom, "//book", saveXML)
listAuthors <- lapply(listBooks, function(book) unlist(xpathSApply(xmlInternalTreeParse(book), "//author/text()", saveXML)))
listAuthors
[[1]]
[1] "Giada De Laurentiis"

[[2]]
[1] "J K. Rowling"

[[3]]
[1] "James McGovern"         "Per Bothner"            "Kurt Cagle"             "James Linn"             "Vaidyanathan Nagarajan"

[[4]]
[1] "Erik T. Ray"
```